# Вывод названия полигонов на карте из пересечения при наведении на пересечение

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Вопрос по API карт. Есть 2 полигона на карте. Один (меньший) находится внутри другого (бОльшего). Как при наведении на меньший полигон вывести название обоих полигонов?
Как вообще можно по API управлять тем, что выводить при наведении на полигон?

Answer (score 0):

Текущее объяснение ситуации не показывает проблемы, если речь о хинте. Если вы сами задаёте маленький полигон внутри большого, что вам мешает сразу задать ему и комбинированный Хинт с информацией из обоих полигонов? Это самое простое решение.